# Configure a non-shadow principal key for this relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to build by database using Code first Entity framework, within a ASP Core 1, RC2 projects.

And I get this error message:

> The key {'TempId'} contains properties in shadow state and is referenced by a relationship from 'TaskStatus' to 'TaskRunner.IsRunning'. Configure a non-shadow principal key for this relationship.

Any one have a idea on what this error means?

Note that I don't have ny column name tempId. I guest that EF7 build this column for itself.

Here is my entity

```
 public class TaskStatus
 {
        public Guid TaskConfigId { get; set; }
        public string LastResultValue { get; set; }
        public int RetryCount { get; set; }
        public TaskStatusEnum StatusEnum { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public TaskResult TaskResult { get; set; }
        public TaskStatusEnum TaskStatusEnum { get; set; }
}

public class TaskRunner
{
    public DateTimeOffset RunAt { get; set; }
    public TaskConfig TaskConfig { get; set; }
    public Guid TaskConfigId { get; set; }
    public TaskStatus IsRunning { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the meening of "contains properties in shadow state"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this by manually specifying a property as the primary key on my models. You might try putting a `[Key]` attribute on TaskConfigId, and maybe adding a primary key field to TaskRunner.

[This bug report](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5655) alludes that using Navigation Properties requires explicit primary keys, rather than letting EF trying to decide which property is the PK based on naming conventions.

I believe Shadow Properties simply means the properties (table columns) that are created to support navigation properties, for example a column named IsRunningTaskStatusId on your TaskRunner table, which contains the primary key of the associated TaskStatus. https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/shadow-properties.html